# How to allocate groups of a data frame based on time in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello I have a table like so:

```
Entry  TimeOn TimeOff Alarm 
  1     60     70      355
  2     80     85      455
  3     100    150     400
  4     105    120     320 
  5     125    130     254
  6     135    155     220
  7     160    170     850
```

I would like to understand how i can group those entries so the ones starting during another alarm and ending either during another alarm or after the other alarm such as entries 4,5 & 6 can be filtered out of the data frame?

so this would be the desired result a dataframe that looked like this:

```
Entry  TimeOn TimeOff Alarm 
  1     60     70      355
  2     80     85      455
  3     100    150     400
  7     160    170     850
```

so entries 4, 5 and 6 removed

Comment: What do the numbers in each column represent?

Comment: please add the **desired result** to your question.

Comment: so entry is just entry number and TImeOn and TimeOff is the number of minutes from the start of the month and alarm is the code for the type of alarm that happened at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df$flag <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
                 nrow(filter(df, data.table::between(x['TimeOn'],df$TimeOn,df$TimeOff)))
                 })

df[df$flag > 1, ]
  Entry TimeOn TimeOff Alarm flag
4     4    105     120   320    2
5     5    125     130   254    2
6     6    135     155   220    2

#Save option using Base R
df$flag <- apply(df,1,function(x) {nrow(df[x['TimeOn'] >= df$TimeOn & x['TimeOn'] <= df$TimeOff,])})
```

Suggested by @Andre Elrico

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) { nrow( df[between(x[['TimeOn']],df$TimeOn,df$TimeOff),] ) > 1 }),]
```

## data

```
df <- read.table(text="
         Entry  TimeOn TimeOff Alarm
             1     60     70      355
             2     80     85      455
             3     100    150     400
             4     105    120     320
             5     125    130     254
             6     135    155     220
             7     160    170     850
             ",header=T)
```

Comment: great, I found that one challenging.

Comment: There is really no need for `dplyr::filter` here: Simply use: `df[apply(df, 1, function(x) { nrow( df[between(x[['TimeOn']],df$TimeOn,df$TimeOff),] ) > 1 }),]` of course I understand and like the `$flag` step.

Comment: @AndreElrico Thanks and of course its if you do not like the intermediate steps but for the newbie like me these intermediate steps unable us to readapt the solution when needed.

Comment: I said I understand and like it :-) .. for exactly that reason. Makes things clear.